# RegEx: Extract Unknown # of Numbers of Unknown Length, With Separators, and Characters to Ignore

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to extract numbers in the format:

> [number]['/' or ' ' or '\' possible, ignore]:['/' or ' ' or '\'
>   possible, ignore][number]['/' or ' ' or '\' possible, ignore]:...

For example:

> "4852/: 5934: 439028/:\23"

Would extract: ['4852', '5934', '439028', '23']

Comment: Just use `\d+` this should work, demo: https://regex101.com/r/wza9Ec/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.findall` to extract all occurrences of a pattern. Note that you should use double backslash to represent a literal backslash in quotes.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', '4852/: 5934: 439028/:\\23')
['4852', '5934', '439028', '23']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does have a regex package [2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), [3.*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

The function that you would probably want to use is the `.split()` function

A code snippet would be

```
import re
numbers = re.split('[/:\]', your_string)
```

The code above would work if thats you only split it based on those non-alphanumeric characters. But you could split it based on all non numeric characters too. like this

```
numbers = re.split('\D+', your_string)
```

or you could do

```
numbers = re.findall('\d+',your_string)
```

Kudos!